# Remove ToggleButton's interactivity but still emitting a signal

Tags: android, togglebutton

I'm sorry but I didn't find in the documentaton a way to do this. I would like to emit the usual signal of a ToggleButton when clicking it but without changing its state. Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: why would you want to do that?

Comment: My app is communicating with a range of electrical plugs. When I'm pressing the On/Off button, a request is sent to the network and the plug replies by sending its information to the phone, which updates the button state (on or off).

Comment: possible duplicate of [ToggleButton state change programmatically rather than automatically in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041021/togglebutton-state-change-programmatically-rather-than-automatically-in-android)

Comment: I saw this topic. One solution would be to create my own ToggleButton, but I wonder if I could it do differently.

Comment: You also need to make it in a way that the user knows the system is taking time because it's working on something.

Comment: You're right. I might display a message to tell the user what's going on. However, the operation should be processed very quickly.